# .NET Core + Visual Studio Code - Organização da estrutura

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-code, .net-core

Tenho aqui comigo algumas dúvidas sobre o desenvolvimento de aplicações em .NET Core usando o Visual Studio Code:

1. Como é criado um projeto base, como por exemplo uma "blank solution", igual no Visual Studio?
2. Como é feito a organização de um projeto .NET Core que segue alguns ou todos os conceitos de DDD. Como se faz essa divisão, por DLL's ?
3. Voltando a primeira questão, é necessário criar uma solução em branco para que possamos organizar melhor o projeto ?

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que consigo responder todas as suas perguntas com um exemplo, mas posso te adiantar que voce vai passar a utilizar a linha de comando, ao invés de realizar todas as operações como é no Visual Studio.

Veja alguns comandos:

```
dotnet new sln # Cria a solution do seu projeto
dotnet new [template_name] -o [output path] # Cria o seu projeto
dotnet sln [sln_name] add [csproj_name] # Adiciona o seu projeto a solution criada.
```

Apenas para exemplificar os comandos acima:

```
dotnet new sln
mkdir src
dotnet new classlib -o src\ProjetoExemplo.Core\
dotnet sln ProjetoExemplo.sln add src\ProjetoExemplo.Core\ProjetoExemplo.Core.csproj
```

Com isso voce consegue compilar os seus projetos separadamente e voce consegue abrir a sua pasta principal do projeto no Visual Studio Code.

Voce pode obter maiores detalhes sobre organização do projeto .net core com uma série de posts do [Scott Allen](https://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2018/09/06/net-core-opinion-2-ndash-managing-a-repository-structure.aspx)

Comment: Fala Nicolas, muito obrigado por responder. Vou testar agora mesmo!

Comment: Nicolas, testei aqui e acho que consegui executar tudo certinho. Uma outra coisa. é normal a solução ficar por ultimo no projeto ?
segue o print: https://imgur.com/7lAFUsn

Comment: Hiroyuki, isso é normal, porque o VS code ordena pelas pastas e depois os arquivos, você pode alterar esta ordenação.
Dentro do VS Code, nas suas configurações, procure por "explorer.sortOrder", você consegue deixar a propriedade Files First habilitada, com isso a sua *.sln ficará antes das pastas. Veja [ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40920775/how-can-i-change-the-file-sorting-of-vs-code)